# Node.js webscraping authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can do this in Python and Ruby, but I wanted to give Node.js a shot and so far the whole scraping process is confusing. I am having trouble with the post request for logging into a site to scrape the data. Here is the code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var credentials = {
    username: 'kevin',
    password: 'secret'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://yourwebsite.com/login',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error('Login failed'));
        return;
    }
});
```

So say I want to scrape after I logged in. Am I replacing the username and password under credentials with the field id? or is it the field name? Also, where is the part where I am hitting submit (button) on form?

Edit: 
Here is the full code on some other site I tried on:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');


var credentials = {
    acct: '....',
    pw: '.....'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/login?whence=news',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
}, function(err, res, body){    

    request('https://news.ycombinator.com', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var text = $('.pagetop').text();

        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: Get something like [_Charles Proxy_](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) installed. Make the requests yourself in a web browser. Look at what's being sent to the server. Then you'll have a good idea about what you need send from your `node.js` code.

Answer (score 0):

> So say I want to scrape after I logged in. Am I replacing the username and password under credentials with the field id? or is it the field name?

If this were an HTML form and it had input text fields named `username` and `password`, then in your `credentials` object  you would have keys for `username` and `password` just as you do now.

> Also, where is the part where I am hitting submit (button) on form?

You're making an HTTP request, not hitting a submit button.  The submit button often has a name just like any other form field input.  If you would like to include it, add it to your `credentials` object.

Comment: What if the input text field name is set to "user[email]". Ok I'll try adding the form field input name on the credentials.

Comment: @user1452530 In that case, put quotes around your key.  `var credentials = { 'user[email]': 'something@example.com' }`

Comment: It still won't login for some reason. I've updated my code using an example on some other site.

Comment: @user1452530 You might consider using something like PhantomJS so that you're running all the site's JavaScript in what not.  In any case, your problem is likely going to come down to cookies.